# Вывод строки на Rectangle с выравниванием по центру

Tags: c#, графика

Столкнулся с такой проблемой что не понимаю как вывести строки на прямоугольник ровно по центру.

Прямоугольник рисуется методом *graphics.FillRectangle(...)*
Строка рисуется методом *graphics.DrawString(...)*

Необходимо вывести ровно по центру прямоугольника строку.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передайте в DrawString [StringAlignment.Center](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7991/5752652):

```
var sf = new StringFormat
{
    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
};

graphics.DrawString("My String", this.Font, Brushes.Black, ClientRectangle, sf);
```